# How do I insert api into a flutter app that requires an api code?

Tags: flutter, api-key

I have an api that I want to enter into a flutter app and it requires a code. The code I have now is based of using a free api that I leaned in an example. I am not sure how to bring in the api by using an api key that was given to me. I eventually want the user to be able to type in their own text and have the api translate it to yoda.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Translator extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _Translator createState() => _Translator();
}

class _Translator extends State<Translator>{

  Future getYoda() async{
    var url = "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda.json";
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var YodaData = jsonDecode('how are you today');
    return YodaData;
  }

  Widget YodaWidget(BuildContext context){
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getYoda(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          Widget myWidget;
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            myWidget = Text("${snapshot.data}");
          } else if(snapshot.hasError){
            myWidget = Text("${snapshot.error}");
          } else {
            myWidget = Column(children:[
              SizedBox(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60
              ),
              const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: Text('Wait no more you must!')
              )
            ]
            );
          }
          return myWidget;
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfffae7652),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xffa4c4a4),
          )
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding:  EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Text("Translator"),
                    YodaWidget(context)


                  ]
              )
          )
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to send the header X-FunTranslations-Api-Secret in the request, for that you need to access the url like below.

```
final Map<String, String> headerData= {
   "X-FunTranslations-Api-Secret": "your api key"
};
Future getYoda() async{
   var url = "https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda.json";
   http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers:headerData);
   var YodaData = jsonDecode('how are you today');
   return YodaData;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do. I keep getting an error on my AVD of "FormatException: Unexpected Character(at character 1) how are you today

Comment: check the API response, it might be returning something unexpected, like with a status of  401 (because of invalid key) or 404 because of your input. please share the complete error (stack trace)

Comment: i checked the API at https://funtranslations.com/api/yoda#endpoint, it seems the API was expecting  a text, which is not presenting in your code. 
try changing the URL to https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda.json?text=Master%20Obiwan%20has%20lost%20a%20planet and test again

Comment: That was the entire error that is showing up in my emulator. It does not show an error in my android studios.

Comment: I tried changing the URL in my code and it is still showing the same error in my emulator.